# How to Query List in C# for multiple values

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have this array, suppose `int[] ageArray=[11,12,13]`

And a list with these objects:

```
 public class temp
 {
     string name;
     string age;
 }
```

Now I want to retrieve all items from the list with `age` in `ageArray`, as size of `ageArray` is not known it will be dynamic. Is this possible using `List.Select` or `List.Where` to query a List using an array.

**For Example**

```
List.Select(row=> row.age in ageArray)
```

this kind of solution?

Comment: If `ageArray` is sorted, consider using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch(v=vs.110).aspx rather than `Contains` to improve performance. Alternatively, change `ageArray` to be a HashSet<int>` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like

```
var result = list.Where(x => ageArray.Contains(x.age)).ToList();
```

Here is a small example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PyhBst